# Текстовая капча на php

Tags: php, xml

Здравствуйте, уважаемые товарищи!

Есть скрипт капчи:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST[submit]){
 if (mb_strtolower(trim($_POST[otvet]), 'UTF-8') == $_SESSION[otvet]) {
  $_SESSION[message] = '<font color="blue">Ответ правильный!</font>';
  // Тут обработка поступившего сообщения из поля text
 }
 else {
  $_SESSION[message] = '<font color="red">Дан неверный ответ!</font>';
 }
header("Location: forms_protection_question.php");    //сбрасываем отправленное
exit();
}
?>

<?php
$question = array(array('Столица России', 'москва'),    //вопросы и ответы
                  array('Спутник Земли', 'луна'),
                  array('Земля вращается вокруг своей ...', 'оси'),
                  array('Семь раз отмерь, один раз ...', 'отрежь'));
$key = rand(0,count($question)-1);        //ключ
$_SESSION[otvet] = $question[$key][1];    //ответ
echo $_SESSION[message];
unset($_SESSION[message]);
?>

<form method="POST" action="forms_protection_question.php">
 <table border="0">
  <tr>
   <td>Текст: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $question[$key][0]; ?></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="otvet"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы вопросы и ответы брались не из массива, а из xml-файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<questions>
  <question key="Крупнейшая река Южной Америки" key2="Амазонка" />
  <question key1="Самое высокое животное" key2="жираф" />
  <question key1="Крупнейшая рыба" key2="китовая акула" />
………
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
$like_xml= <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <questions>
        <question key1="Крупнейшая река Южной Америки" key2="Амазонка" />
        <question key1="Самое высокое животное" key2="жираф" />
        <question key1="Крупнейшая рыба" key2="китовая акула" />
    </questions>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($like_xml); // simplexml_load_file()

$quiz = $xml->xpath('/questions/question');

$key = rand(0,count($quiz)-1);

// вывести рандомную пару вопрос-ответ
echo $quiz[$key]['key1'] . " - " . $quiz[$key]['key2'];

/* output:
Крупнейшая река Южной Америки - Амазонка
Самое высокое животное - жираф
Крупнейшая рыба - китовая акула    
*/
```

В примере грузим переменную $like_xml, для загрузки из файла - [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: Честно говоря я не пойму, как это сочетать с моим скриптом? Загрузка xml, мне ясна, но как вставить атрибут в строку в форме, что бы первые ключи выводились бы рандомно? Другими словами, мне нужно сделать в данном конкретном примере. С массивом в теле скрипта всё работает, но, как ваш пример интегрировать в скрипт, мне не ясно.

Comment: @Linne то что в вопросе $question, то в ответе $quiz. А дальше всё то же самое с тем отличием, что в $quiz - набор объектов SimpleXMLElement. Их перебирать аки массив. Обновил в ответе.

Comment: Теперь всё ясно :) Спасибо большое!